# AOSP init: starting service logcatd fails

Tags: android, android-source, logcat, init

Dearest StackOverflow,

I have been working at a company for about 8 months (still learning), and we have an array of devices in production and out in the field which run on modified **Android 6** and **Android 8**. I've been marginally successful, with our OTA update packages. Applying an A8-ota to A8 works, and the same for A6. However an issue persists when applying an Android 8 OTA update onto a device running Android 6. In other words, I am trying to upgrade Android 6 to Android 8 using an OTA update.

**updater-script** says it completed successfully. Still things are buggy.

The current issue is that after rebooting, I cannot get past the splash screen (uh-oh). Even worse, **logcatd** doesn't startup properly, so I have no logs to read off. When I try to start the service `start logcatd` the serial terminal spits out:

```
init: starting service 'logcatd'...
init: property_set("ro.boottime.logcatd", "1447586056838") failed: property already set
init: Service 'logcatd' (pid 304) exited with status 1
init: Sending signal 9 to service 'logcatd' (pid 304) process group...
init: kill(-304, 9) failed: No such process
init: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1036 pid 304 in 4ms
      :::
      (reapeating)
```

So I have a few newbie questions:

1. How can I go about debugging this? The **/system** partition does get formatted before all files are copied over (but now I'm not too sure)
2. What is **ro.boottime.logcatd** and where can I find it ()?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `ro.boottime.logcatd` is a property that is used for performance analysis, it logs the timestamp of when the service was first started. You can inspect it with `adb shell getprop ...`. If a service crashes and is restarted, the property will not set again (resulting in the "property already set" log message), but this should not be fatal. So I would assume there is some other reason for why the service crashes. I would try to start logcatd manually (instead of via `start`), so `stop logcatd` and then just `logcatd` or `strace logcatd`. Maybe this gives you more information about why it fails.

Comment: Also A8 reworked the SE Linux implementation (as part of Project Treble), so it might be worth a try to disable SE Linux temporarily (e.g. via `setenforce 0`) to check if it is causing problems.

Comment: Some other things I would consider: Has the boot image been updated correctly (holding the kernel)? You could use e.g. `uname -a` to check if the expected kernel version is being booted. Is the OEM image being updated (holding vendor-specific binary blobs)? If it is not being updated, is the existing OEM image compatible with A8? You could check this by manually flashing A8 on a A6 device to see if it boots.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give me some pointers. And here are the results:

Starting manually with `logcatd` output `# logcat read failure`. And after spending some time to understand the output of **strace**, it showed 16 errors = 2 with **openat**, and 14 with **faccessat**.

The two **openat** calls were:
`openat(AT_FDCWD, "/system/lib/libnetd_client.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3`
 ... 
`openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:logd_prop:s0", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC) = 3`

Secondly, `setenforce 0` did not improve things.

Comment: `uname -a` outputs `Linux localhost 4.9.88`

I have to ask, what do you specifically mean by flashing A8 onto device? I've got USB updates, `adb sync` ... I never quite know what is meant exactly.

Comment: Kernel version looks ok for A8. I meant flashing as in `adb reboot-bootloader`, `fastboot flash boot boot.img` (repeat for system.img, recovery.img and userdata.img). I'm not 100% sure if there are device-dependent steps that might be different for you.

Comment: Regarding logcatd, I get the same failure for `libnetd_client`, that should be ok. The `logcat read failure` might be your best guess (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-8.1.0_r77/logcat/logcat.cpp#1641). I would try to put some debug messages into the `android_logger_list_read` function, recompile and `adb push` the modified `liblog.so` onto the device.

Answer (score 1):

For completion, I will answer my own question here.

Another hint presented itself when the context properties of the system partition was checked, for example `ls -Z /system/bin` produced:

```
   :::
u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 bootanimation    
u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 bootstat         
u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 bu               
u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 bugreport        
u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 bugreportz       
u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 bunzip2          
u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 bzcat            
u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 bzip2    
   :::   (etc)
```

NO labelling was done during the OTA update. The **updater-script** in the A8 OTA had a condition that would read from the environment (ie. the Anroid 6 recovery) if SELinux was 'enabled' or not. For Android 6 this was "disabled" which Android 8 OTA would then read and then not apply the SELinux labels ... and a mess was made.